Animated (short?) film about a psychic girl fighting an alien invasion
Is saw this in the late 90's on a pay per view special on Sky, it was stop-motion animation (I think).
The film is about this girl with telekinesis of some sort, she can move objects etc, the film starts with her living with her parents when a space ship arrives to Earth and destroys the city.
I remember this scene where the girl picks up her parents' skulls from the debris of her house.
Then I don't remember exactly how, but she finds two aliens, and they help her and take her to the spaceship.
I remember the film ends with a shot of more spaceships coming down to Earth, and the girl saying something like "The battle just begun" of something like that. 

Sounds like the exact plot of the Spanish stop-motion film Juego de ninos from 1999, but according to IMDb, it's not that short after all (70 minutes).

Sara is an orphan child in a world destroyed by an alien invasion. Leaving behind her innocence, Sara unleashes the power of her psychokinetic abilities to survive the attacks of the invaders and free the human survivors.

In fact, what you seem to be describing is the trailer, which contains everything you mentioned including the skulls and the ending with her defiant on a ship:



Another clip, with the girl's town being destroyed, can be found here.
